# Evaluating a limit with Mclaurin series

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to evaluate the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{\tan^2 x}-\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right)$$

I have identified that 
$$\dfrac{1}{\tan(x)} = \cot(x)$$

and 
$$\cot x = \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{x}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

which means that 
$$\cot^2x = \dfrac{1}{x^2} - \dfrac{x^2}{9} + \mathcal{O}(x^6)$$

Now I don't know how to proceed - according to Wolframalpha, the series I should get is supposed to be 
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{x^2}{15} + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$$
and because there is a constant in there I assume that will be my final answer since the $x^4$ "grows faster" than the denominator in $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\cot ^{2}x &=&\left( \frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{3})\right) ^{2}=(%
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3})^{2}+2(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3})\mathcal{O}(x^{3})+%
\mathcal{O}(x^{6}) \\
&=&\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{x^{2}}{9}+2\frac{1}{x}\mathcal{O}%
(x^{3})=\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{2}{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{2}).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
In order to obtain the Wolfram expression you have to expand one term
further to obtain the coefficient of $x^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbf{(x+y)^{2}\ne x^{2}+y^{2}!!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your start is good but when you squared $\cot(x)$, you forgot the cross product. Refer to Daniel Littlewood's explicit answer.